# Change HTML attribute in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

How would I change the `class` attribute in my HTML to "night nosmoke" using JavaScript?

```
<div id="imperium" class="day nosmoke" style="margin-left: -800px; margin-top: -600px;">
```

I've tried copying the jspath then look at innerHTML but that just brings other stuff up.

Comment: *change day into night here with javascript* o_O

Comment: If you look closer, this is actually a genuine question, based on the experience of the user with js/html ... Just change the class with Javascript like so: `document.getElementById("imperium").className = "night nosmoke";` Here's more to view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/how-can-i-change-an-elements-class-with-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess this is what you mean. Remove `day` class and add `night` class to the element:

```js
document.getElementById('imperium').classList.remove('day');// <---- Remove day
document.getElementById('imperium').classList.add('night'); //<---add class night
console.log(document.getElementById('imperium'))
```

```html
<div id="imperium" class="day nosmoke" style="margin-left: -800px; margin-top: -600px;">
```